# Page keeps on refreshing infinitely if $('body').html() is updated dynamically

Tags: jquery, replace, document-ready

I have a page where all scripts are moved to the bottom, just before closing the 'body' tag.
This page may contain a special symbol that has to be replaced dynamically on $(document).ready().

For such cases I usually use this simple trick:

```
$('body').html($('body').html().replace('special_symbol', 'new_value'));
```

This code works fine if scripts are located in header.

But if scripts are moved to bottom, this code leads to infinite page refreshes.
So, the question is: Is it possible to update whole body HTML dynamically, without infinite refreshes? 
Or may be there is a better way to update an html substing dynamically without specifying its parent class or id?

UPD: Found a better solution of replacing that special_symbol:

```
replaceTextInDom('original_value', 'new_value');
...
function replaceTextInDom(original_value, new_value){   
    var reg_exp =  new RegExp(original_value, 'g');
    $('div:contains('+original_value+')').each(function(){      
        if ($(this).clone().children('div').remove().end().text().indexOf(original_value) >= 0)
            $(this).html($(this).html().replace(reg_exp, new_value));
    });         
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a back end problem to me.

Comment: That's some pretty terrible "simple trick" you've got there.

Answer (score 1):

It might look like a simple trick, but it's one of the ugliest pieces of JavaScript I've ever seen.

Your code grabs the entire HTML of the page, as a text string, and then does a replace of `special_cymbol` with `new_value`, and then re-draws **the entire page** when you update it. Overkill much?

Anyway, here's what's happening:

Like I said, this line - `$('body').html()` - grabs the entire HTML as a text string. What is located in that HTML? Your script tags. So when you update the HTML of the entire page, you're also re-adding your  tags, which are downloaded, parsed, and executed again, which is where your javascript code that updates the page lives, which will then do the exact same thing over and over and over and over again.

**EDIT**

Don't do what you are doing, it's horrible. If you need to update the text `special_cymbol`, then every time you output it on your page, do it like this:

```
<span class="special_cymbol_class">special_cymbol</span>
```

And then you can just do this:

```
$('.special_cymbol_class').html('new_value');
```

Comment: yes, I agree, replacing whole html is not an elegant solution. 
If that special symbol could be wrapped in a container with a certain class it would be a lot easier. 
But this special symbol may appear in any container without any class. Is there any other way to replace 'special_symbol' inside html without knowing its container class?

Comment: I think I found a more elegant solution to replace that special symbol: 
`$(':contains(special_symbol)').each(function(){
  if ($(this).html().indexOf('special_symbol') == 1)
   $(this).html($(this).html().replace('special_symbol', 'Docs'));
 });`
What do you think about it?

Comment: @Amazzing - `$(':contains(special_symbol))` - is far far worse. It will return every DOM node that has `special_symbol` in it's innerHTML, starting with the `html` node, then the `body` node, and so on and so on - it's actually way worse than what you were doing originally. Using jQuery is just the wrong way to accomplish what you're doing, despite the fact that it may "work".

Comment: Well, you can see a condition:
if ($(this).html().indexOf('special_symbol') == 1)
so it returns only elemens, that don't have any children and start with that special symbol.

In either case, if this approach is not good as well, what you think would be the best way to find special symbol without its parent class or id?

Comment: @Amazzing - that does nothing. Run this snippet on the current page in your console: `$(':contains(re-draws)').each(function() { console.log($(this).html().indexOf('re-draws')); });`. You think your problem is: 'how can I update special_symbol if it doesn't have a parent class or id' - your problem actually is: 'how can I wrap special_symbol in a class at the time it is outputted on a page from the server?'

Comment: Adam, if I could wrap it before output, I could replace it at the same time. In this particular case I don't have access to editing output contents.

Comment: How about this code?
`var special_symbol = 're-draws';
 $('div:contains('+special_symbol+')').each(function(){
  if ($(this).html().split('<div')[0].indexOf(special_symbol) >= 0){
   console.log($(this).html().split('<div')[0].indexOf(special_symbol));
   var reg_exp =  new RegExp(special_symbol, 'g');
   $(this).html($(this).html().replace(reg_exp, 'new_val'));   
  }
 });` 
Try running it in your console. You can see that only divs, containing special_symbol are affected.

Answer (score 1):

Try utilizing [jQuery.parseHTML](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parseHTML/), setting third argument `jQuery.parseHTML( data [, context ] [, keepScripts ] )` to `false`

```
var body = $("body");
var html = $.parseHTML(body.html(), document, false);
$(html).each(function(i, html) {
    return $(html).text(function(_, text) {
      return text.replace(/special_cymbol/, "new_value")
    })
});
body.html(html);
```

```js
    var body = $("body");
    var html = $.parseHTML(body.html(), document, false);
    $(html).each(function(i, html) {
        return $(html).text(function(_, text) {
          return text.replace(/special_cymbol/, "new_value")
        })
    });
    body.html(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <body>
      <script>
        console.log($.now())
      </script>
      <div>abc</div>
      <div>special_cymbol</div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I am looking for a solution with as less loops as possible.

Comment: By mentioning as less loops as possible I meant avoid unrequired processings. Basing on your previous code, replace was applied on each document element. 

I tried the new code you offered, it throws error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined

Comment: Which line ? Not appear where a `parentNode` is referenced at current piece ? Yes, at previous piece replace utilized on every _remaining_ element , after `script` elements removed from collection

Comment: Tried that code on another site. It removes all tags and replaces body html with plain text.

Please take a look at my upate in first post. What do you think about it?

Comment: @Amazzing See OP at _"So, the question is: Is it possible to update **whole body HTML** dynamically"_ ; at "UPD" : `$('div:contains('+original_value+')')` ?

Comment: You are right, that's my mistake. edited initial post.

Comment: @Amazzing The update at OP , perhaps, renders _two_ different questions ?  "whole body HTML" appear different than "html substing" ? Especially where original question included consideration of `script` elements _"But if scripts are moved to bottom, this code leads to infinite page refreshes."_ ?

Comment: OK, you answered an initial question and you have a +1 from me.